# How to cover setup audit trail object in test class

Tags: unit-test, batch, setup-audit-log

I have wrote batch class for setupaudittrail object. 
In start method query string is

`String query = 'SELECT CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Username, Display, Section, Action, DelegateUser,CreatedById,CreatedBy.Name FROM SetupAuditTrail ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC';`

How to cover this setup audit trail in test class?

Answer (score 3):

You can test the batch class just as you would test any other batch test class.

The only difference is that you don't have to set up test data upfront. SetupAuditTrail records cannot be created from APEX (the [object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm) only supports `Query()` and `Retrieve()`) but all the audit trail records in your instance are always visible in test context. You don't even need to specify `SeeAllData=true`.

So a simple example test class could be this (assuming your batch class name is `SetupAuditTrailBatch`):

```
@isTest
private class TestSetupAuditTrailBatchClass {
   static testmethod void test() {
      Test.startTest();
      SetupAuditTrailBatch c = new SetupAuditTrailBatch();
      Database.executeBatch(c);
      Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

And depending on the purpose of your code, you should add Test.Assert methods to check that the code functioned as expected.

Comment: System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.

Comment: following error has been occured

Comment: yeah that's a known limitation of batch class testing. See here for the workaround: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176562&language=en_US  To further help you I'd need to see the full code.